# LINQ Intersect but add the result to a New List

Tags: c#, linq, intersect

I have a list called DiscountableObject. Each item on the list in turn has a Discounts collection. What I need is a list of Discounts which are common across all DiscoubtableObjects.

Code:

```
List<Discount> IntersectionOfDiscounts = new List<Discount>();
foreach(var discountableItem in DiscoutableObject)
{
    IntersectionOfDiscounts = IntersectionOfDiscounts.Intersect(discountableItem.Discounts);    
}
```

This will undoubtedly return an empty list because by IntersectionOfDiscounts was empty in the first instance.

What I want is to take item 1 of the DiscountableObject, compare it with the next item of DiscountableObject and so on.

I know what I am trying to do is wrong because, I am doing the intersection and the addition to the list at the same time...but how else baffles me?

How do I get around this?

Comment: How about adding some test data to your example and providing what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `IntersectionOfDiscounts` to the first Discount List (if there is more than one) rather than to an empty list.  You can also then skip the first item in the 'foreach' loop.

```
// add check to ensure at least 1 item.
List<Discount> IntersectionOfDiscounts = DiscoutableObject.First().Discounts; 
foreach(var discountableItem in DiscoutableObject.Skip(1))
{
    IntersectionOfDiscounts = IntersectionOfDiscounts.Intersect(discountableItem.Discounts);    
}
```

Comment: There must be a more elegant way than this... but yes, it'll work :)

Comment: You could make a new `IEnumerable` extension for Intersect that performed an intersect on N Enumerables (i.e. an Enumerable of Enumerables) if you did this often enough.

Comment: Duh! I now feel like an idiot! Will mark the answer as accepted in 6 minutes unless there is a better one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly more elegant way:

```
var intersection = discountableObject
   .Select(discountableItem => discountableItem.Discounts)
   .Aggregate( (current, next) => current.Intersect(next).ToList());
```

Missed your 6 minute deadline, but I like it anyway...